# Using toString on case classes to generate a value is a good or bad practice?

Tags: scala

I have a `case class` let's say:

```
case class Offset(a:String, b:Int, c: UUID) {
 override def toString: String = productIterator.mkString(",")
}

val offset: String = Offset("some_String", 2, java.util.UUID.randomUUID).toString
```

Is it fine to `override toString` method on case class or shall I implement a different method let's say `generateOffset` which does the same thing like:

```
case class Offset(a:String, b:Int, c: UUID) {
  def generateOffset: String = productIterator.mkString(",")
}

val offset: String = Offset("some_String", 2, java.util.UUID.randomUUID).generateOffset
```

Comment: It seems that your offset is of type `String`,
Maybe `generateOffset` should be renamed to `rawRepresentation` or just `flat` or something like that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`toString` is used by people and debugging tools. So it should contain concise human readable information. 
You should not base your logic on `toString`

Second version is more clear, at least for me.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your case class usage.
Overriding `toString` method will give you many good features, like custom string interpolation:

```
val offset = Offset("some_String", 2, java.util.UUID.randomUUID)
val str = s"""Offset object is $offset"""
```

Scala will call your toString method under the hood and insert it in string.

So in general this is good idea.